# is there any way to "control" slot execution with boost::signals2?

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots, boost-signals

I am working on a NotificationCenter using boost::signals2.

I have to integrate it into a Reactor-like system and I have a concern... if there are too many handlers subscribed to a signal I would like to be able to stop subscribers handler execution and return flow control to Reactor to avoid being unresponsive for too many time, and resume execution later on ...

Is there any way to implement this?

I have been looking at Combiners ... but I think that is not the right way ...

Any advice will be welcomed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think of combiners too. Or some kind of cooperative control